# Best way to check non null precondition in typescript

Tags: typescript, if-statement, null

Imagine a firebase timestamp that you want to check for equality like so:

```
if (!a.timestamp.isEqual(b.timestamp){
   //Do stuff because timestamp of a and b are not equal
}
```

This obviously fails if a is null or if timestamp of a is null (Does this also fail if timestamp of b is null?). Lets assume a and b are not null. What is the best way to ensure that the above statement works. This seems way to complicated:

```
if (a.timestamp === null && b.timestamp !== null ||
    a.timestamp !== null && b.timestamp === null ||  
    a.timestamp !== null && !a.timestamp.isEqual(b.timestamp))
{
        //Do stuff because timestamp of a and b are not equal
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if they are both null, and therefore equal?

Comment: Well a is before update and b is after update. I am writing to a different document whenever there was a change from a to b. So best would be if both are null the if should be skipped (as this saves me a transaction and in the end money)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit:

```
if ((a.timestamp === null && b.timestamp !== null) ||
    (a.timestamp !== null && !a.timestamp.isEqual(b.timestamp)) )
```

Then, if a is null it checks if b is null, if they are both null it skips but if b is not null then it get treated like a non-equal.

In all other cases where a is not null, then the `isEqual` method exists and worlds correctly.

Comment: This does not work does it? If a is null and b is null the first condition is false and since there is an 'or' the second condition has to be evaluated which would crash since a is null

Comment: Yup my bad, missed out the second !==null, added it back in

Comment: Okay, i see that i can get rid of the one condition. Okay. Thank you. It kind of bothers me that we have to write so much boilderplate code just because of the 'null' checks. I will put it in a seperate function

Comment: You could maybe check each of them for null before you get to this part of the code, and then just have `a.timestamp.isEqual(b.timestamp))` in that if statement.